# Use python packages from another docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

How can I use python packages from another container?

`ydk-py` is set up with everything that I need, including all python packages and their dependencies.
I want to use those python packages in my django application. However python imports packages installed in my main container, `web`, and not `ydk-py`.

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    container_name: webserver
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: database
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env.dev

  ydk-py:
    container_name: ydk-py
    image: ydkdev/ydk-py:latest
    tty: true

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.12-alpine

WORKDIR /code

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /code/entrypoint.sh

COPY . /code

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/code/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to use `ydk-py` as your base image to build your application

```
FROM ydkdev/ydk-py:latest
...
```

Comment: I should've clarified why I wanted to have `webserver` and `ydk-py` in their own containers. The reason is that `ydk-py` runs in Ubuntu 16.04 and has an old version of python3 installed that is going to be deprecated in January of 2021. Now I can easily upgrade the python version but am not sure whether it is possible/easy to upgrade the underlying Ubuntu version!

Comment: `ydk-py` is open source, you can rebuild it with more recent versions https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/ydk-py

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for the help :)